# Native crashes on detachAnimators

Tags: android, crash, native

We have recently released a new Android app on Google Play and I have noticed several native crashes, happening on devices running Android 8 - 9. Unfortunately we cannot reproduce the crashes on any of our devices. It looks like the crash has to do with low-level drawing (canvas functions) and according to some other posts it may have to do with hardware acceleration - however I have found no information that explains what this is and how to fix it. Can someone help on how we can troubleshoot this issue?

Here is the crash with the most instances...

```
  #00  pc 000000000001cc96  /system/lib/libc.so (abort+58)
  #00  pc 0000000000006ccd  /system/lib/liblog.so (__android_log_assert+156)
  #00  pc 000000000000bab1  /system/lib/libutils.so (android::sp_report_race()+12)
  #00  pc 00000000000a9ddd  /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so (android::RootRenderNode::detachAnimators()+212)
  #00  pc 00000000000a8987  /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so (android::AnimationContextBridge::destroy()+10)
  #00  pc 000000000046a8e9  /system/lib/libhwui.so (android::uirenderer::renderthread::CanvasContext::destroy()+76)
  #00  pc 000000000046ccaf  /system/lib/libhwui.so (std::__1::packaged_task<void ()>::operator()()+50)
  #00  pc 0000000000432f9f  /system/lib/libhwui.so (android::uirenderer::WorkQueue::process()+122)
  #00  pc 0000000000159e5f  /system/lib/libhwui.so (android::uirenderer::renderthread::RenderThread::threadLoop()+178)
  #00  pc 000000000000c0df  /system/lib/libutils.so (android::Thread::_threadLoop(void*)+166)
  #00  pc 0000000000063325  /system/lib/libc.so (__pthread_start(void*)+22)
  #00  pc 000000000001de59  /system/lib/libc.so (__start_thread+24)
```

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem, a lot of crashes but failed to reproduce on a real device

The issue seems reported here: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/173906153